# Looping Issue - AJAX/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, loops

So i spent some time over night adding user pictures to a voting feature we have, and all is working nicely, however we notice that as users pictures show up as who voted, it repeats the results twice, instead of a row of pictures going across per item.

So per item, users picture (who voted on the poll ID) shows up but duplicates the row.

Does this have to do with **$.each()** ? How can I iterate the photos across each row (id column) without creating a copy of the answer and not show only 1 picture?

```
function fetchPollData() {
    $(function(){});
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax_pollresults.php",
            method: "GET",
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (data) {          
                var html_to_append = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var scase = (item.votes > 1) ? 'votes' : 'vote';
                    html_to_append +=
                        '<div class="content poll-result"><div class="wrapper"><div class="poll-question"><p>' +
                        item.title +
                        ' - <span style="font-weight:bold">' + item.votes + ' ' + scase + ' <img class="tooltip-polluser" title="' + item.username + ' - Voted: ' + item.title + '" href="/user/?id=' + item.user_id + '" style="width:25px;height:25px;border-radius:50%;margin-left:10px;vertical-align:middle" src="/' + item.avatar + '" /></span></p><div class="result-bar" style="width:' + roundVotes(item.votes) + '%"><b>' + item.votes + '</b>&nbsp;' + scase + ' </div></div></div></div>';
                });
                $("#recent-poll").html(html_to_append);
                $('.tooltip-polluser').tooltipster({
                    animation: 'grow',
                    delay: 200,
                    theme: 'tooltipster-punk'
                });
            }
        });
}
fetchPollData();
setInterval(function () {
    fetchPollData()
}, 10000);
```

The bug we cant figure out a fix for:

[image: The results bug]

It seems it is only showing 1 user per voted item, and ignoring the rest of the row.

our SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    poll_answers.id AS id,
    IFNULL(poll_users.user_id, '') AS user_id,
    IFNULL(users.username, '') AS username,
    poll_answers.poll_id,
    poll_answers.title,
    poll_answers.votes,
    poll_users.added AS date,
    IFNULL(users.avatar_thumb,
            'images/poll_avatarfix.png') AS avatar
FROM
    poll_answers
        LEFT JOIN
    poll_users ON poll_users.poll_id = poll_answers.poll_id
        LEFT JOIN
    users ON users.user_id = poll_users.user_id
```

And the database results:

[image]

I spent a fair bit of the evening writing this SQL query, so I'm not sure if this is the query not bringing all avatars out or if its jQuery.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to get each voter image in an inner loop. You can do something like the following...

Instead of using just the one record, call something like `getVoteImages()` and pass in the poll id you are looking for. This will get all of your images and append them to a string then return it. There may be faster, more elegant ways to do it, but this should work.

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
            var scase = (item.votes > 1) ? 'votes' : 'vote';
            html_to_append +=
                '<div class="content poll-result"><div class="wrapper"><div class="poll-question"><p>' +
                item.title +
                ' - <span style="font-weight:bold">' + item.votes + ' ' + scase + getVoteImages(data, item.poll_id)  + "</span></p><div class="result-bar" style="width:' + roundVotes(item.votes) + '%"><b>' + item.votes + '</b>&nbsp;' + scase + ' </div></div></div></div>';
        });
```

```
function getVoteImages(data, poll_id) {
        var images = "";
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            if (item.poll_id == poll_id) {
                images += ' <img class="tooltip-polluser" title="' + item.username + ' - Voted: ' + item.title + '" href="/user/?id=' + item.user_id + '" style="width:25px;height:25px;border-radius:50%;margin-left:10px;vertical-align:middle" src="/' + item.avatar + '" />';
            }
        });

        return images;
    }
```

Comment: That worked fantastic! Thank you, maybe I can use this method to pull the answers so they do not repeat twice (or this is a issue with my SQL query). I appreciate your time